# Greek letters like in comprehensive symbol list

Tags: greek

I am getting horrible greek letters in my equations (see image below). I would like to get alpha and beta as shown in table 188 of the comprehensive symbol list. Do I have to use some special package?

[image]

*Addendum*: I am using the following packages. Is any of them responsible of modyfing the font?

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsthm}
% Symbols
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{stix}
% \usepackage{sidecap}
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={6in, 8in}]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage[font={small,it}]{caption}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{units}

% FIGURES ===========
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{framed}
```

Comment: You are using a different font than the default, use the default Computer Modern and you will see the same output.

Comment: You get alpha and beta. The exact shape is unimportant. Since you're using the STIX fonts, you get the shape coming with the font design. Mixing different fonts is not good typographic practice.

Comment: I use stix only because of \smallin. Is there any way to limit its effect to this symbol?

Comment: In `unicode-math`, it’s easy to load one symbol from a different font: `\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}` followed by `\setmathfont{XITS Math[range=\smallin, Scale=MatchUppercase]`. In legacy NFSS, you need to look through the documentation for the font tables of `stix`, to find which symbol font to load and which 8-bit code to use for that math symbol. Sometimes, you also have to load different display/text/script versions with `\mathchoice`.

Comment: I have tried to import one symbol but I can't get it to work.